# Why my Junit tests are returning Null or 0?

Tags: mockito, junit5

My test class is saying that assertEquals is failing with result value as 0, and for other methods involving objects as null.

I guess this is not a problem with gradle as this is not the first test contributed to the project, others have also written test cases for the repository layer.

Below is my Test class:

```java
@DisplayNameGeneration(DisplayNameGenerator.Simple.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class DorRepositoryTest {

    @Mock
    EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Mock
    EntityManager em;

    @Mock
    Query mockedQuery;

    @Mock
    DorRepository dorRepository;
    
    @Test
    void getDorByGuidTest() {

        Long id = 72L;
        List<Dor> expected = List.of(new Dor());

        expected.get(0).setid(guid);
       

        when(emf.createEntityManager()).thenReturn(em);
        when(em.createNativeQuery(any(String.class))).thenReturn(mockedQuery);
        when(mockedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(expected);

        List<Dor> result = DorRepository.getDorByid(id);
        assertEquals(1, result.size());

    }
```

Note: DorRepository is an Interface.

Slacktrace :

```java
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <1> but was: <0>
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:150)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:145)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:527)
    at app//com..repository.DorRepositoryTest.getDorByGuidTest(DorRepositoryTest.java:71)
    at java.base@11.0.16/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.16/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base@11.0.16/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Everything in your test is a mock. You should have at least one non-mock object - the one you are testing. Should it be `DorRepository` in this test?

Comment: To state the obvious, `DorRepository.getDorByid` is returning an empty list. Perhaps you should debug your way into `DorRepository.getDorByid` and see if you can figure out **why** it's returning an empty list.

Comment: @MinasMina the point is its a jpa repository so cant instantiate it. Another thing its a native query will that be making any difference.

Comment: @BobJarvis-СлаваУкраїні  It worked when @autowired was used and alone `@springboottest` is used. Can you tell what was happening?